# Unable to start VNC server from PHP

Tags: php, environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to get PHP to start up vncserver environment before it starts up a gameserver.

```
if(isset($_POST['start-1']))
{   putenv('HOME=/home/psych/');
    shell_exec('sh /home/psych/mw3/Infected/start.sh');
    echo "SERVER 1 STARTED";
}
```

when i check my apache logs i get this error every time...

```
vncserver: The HOME environment variable is not set.
```

Here is what's in start.sh

```
vncserver -geometry 1000x800 -depth 24
cd /home/psych/mw3/Infected/
screen -d -m bash -c "export DISPLAY=:1 ; server.exe -param1 -param2";
```

How can i set HOME or avoid it checking so my php can start the server?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I went off export `HOME=/home/psych` and got this

```
vncserver: Could not create /home/psych//.vnc.
```

I then tried `export HOME=/`and got this...

```
vncserver: Could not create //.vnc.
```

I just need a hand with what comes after `HOME=`

Cheers

Comment: If you are running the HTTP server with a user who is different than psych, then the second part of your query is probably a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```
shell_exec('export HOME=/home/psych && sh /home/psych/mw3/Infected/start.sh');
```

Or, try adding (to the beginning of `start.sh`):

```
export HOME
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There's 3 things that need to be done:

1. Change your permissions in `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` to be the following:

   `allowed_users=anybody`
2. Add a home directory to the script:  ex: `export HOME=/var/www/`
3. Add a user variable to the script: ex: `export USER=www-data`